# Opaque always change to alpha blend after export as .Fbx

Tags: modeling, export, transparency, .fbx, blend-modes

I quite new to blender just start model my first model. After I finished and export with .fbx file. I found out that my export model blend mode changed from opaque to alpha blend like this and I dont know how to solve this problem. Hope you guys can help[image] me.